# Magento2 REST API products list and out of stock

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, inventory, out-of-stock

In the api call V1/products i get also out of stock products, even though I've set in Stores->configuration->catalog->inventory "Display out of stock products" to No.
there's a way to get rid of this annoing missing feature?

Comment: Did you ever found out about this? Stock levels also don't seem to be listed in the data that comes back, so you never quite know what is in and what is out of stock..

Answer (score 0):

Magento Core team better look and fix this issue is still exist in 2.2.7 and I fixed it with a plugin in my custom module and I also added a bonus for you; this also allows you to filter products by website and store id

1. Custom/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <!--
> /**
>  * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
>  * See COPYING.txt for license details.
>  */
> -->
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
> <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection">
>     <plugin name="instockFilter" type="Custom\ModuleName\Model\Plugin\InstockFilter" />
> </type>
>
> </config>
> ```

2. configuration = $configuration;
             $this->stockHelper = $stockHelper;
         }

         public function aroundAddFieldToFilter(ProductCollection $subject, \Closure $proceed, $fields, $condition = null)
         {
             if ($this->configuration->isShowOutOfStock() != 1) {
                 $this->stockHelper->addInStockFilterToCollection($subject);
             }

             if (is_array($fields)) {
                 foreach ($fields as $key => $filter) {
                     if ($filter['attribute'] == 'website_id' && isset($filter['eq'])) {
                         $subject->addWebsiteFilter([$filter['eq']]);
                         unset($fields[$key]);
                     } else if ($filter['attribute'] == 'store_id' && isset($filter['eq'])) {
                         $subject->addStoreFilter($filter['eq']);
                         unset($fields[$key]);
                     }
                 }
             }

             return $fields? $proceed($fields, $condition) : $subject;
         }
     }`

Comment: It dosen't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below procedure

create a di.xml in webrest_api folder and add below xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection">
        <plugin name="add_stock_information" type="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\AddStockStatusToCollection" />
    </type>
```